# Can't log into Ubuntu 14.04 after update, login loop, incorrect login in tty

Tags: 14.04, login

My relatives updated their Ubuntu and couldn't log into it after that. After entering password the screen blinked to black and returned to the login screen. When I saw the screen there was an Ubuntu user and a Guest user. I tried `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and tried to log in as Ubuntu user it gave me "Incorrect login" error but the password was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a fair amount of time I was able to solve this problem which I want to share with community.

Problem one was that user name wasn't Ubuntu. It was **home**.

The second problem was that Ubuntu installed Nvidia drivers for the ATI Radeon video card.

To find user name out I booted Ubuntu into recovery mode by selecting it in grub menu. And then I chose the root console. Where I typed

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

from a long list of weird usernames I made an assumption it's home and was right. Restarted computer with `Ctrl + Alt + Delete`. During login screen pressed `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and logged in as **home** user.

By that time my relatives remembered that before update Ubuntu said something about Nvidia. But I knew they had ATI Radeon video card. So I wiped out all Nvidia drivers and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop using these commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Rebooted with `Ctrl + Alt + Delete` and it worked. Hope this helps somebody